# Atlas of a given surface

Tags: calculus, parametric

How do we go about finding the atlas (collection of homeomorphisms/surface patches) of any given surface, for instance, if the surface is:
$\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbf{R}^{3} : x = y^2\}$?

Comment: 1. For an arbitrary implicit smooth surface, finding a parametrization is Difficult. Are you really interested only in the example you gave? 2. The question as stated isn't differential geometry or Riemann surfaces; if there's motivation coming from either area, please edit your question and re-tag.

Comment: http://touch-geometry.karazin.ua/list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explizit, one can use

$$\eqalign{
  & \left( {u,v} \right) \in {\mathbb{R}^2}  \cr 
  & {\varphi ^{ - 1}}\left( {u,v} \right) = \left( {{u^2},u,v} \right) \cr} $$

as parametriztion, and

$$\begin{gathered}
  \left( {x,y,z} \right) \in {\mathbb{R}^3} \hfill \\
  \varphi \left( {x,y,z} \right) = \left( {y,z} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$

as projection.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** View the surface as the graph of a particular function of $(y, z)$.